# Setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated [bubble diagram] using Beamer

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

It is needed setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated using Beamer from slide <5->, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%Color boxes start with a 
%small but noticeable space, which can be annoying 
%when highlighting whole lines of Python 
%where indentation matters, this command prevent it.
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{graphics}%scalebox

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}%Fuente tipo mano para pizarra en Beamer
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}%Paquetes para organigramas
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{dtklogos}
%Paquetes para Beamer
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{adjustbox}%Para centrar tablas
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
% set text colors for different objects
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}
%% set fonts
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}
%% Green Background Colour
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!18!black}
%% Random Dust Trails
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, \the\paperheight); 
      \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(0,10000)/5000-1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(0,10000)/10000-0.1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,10000)/1000-5}%
            \rotatebox{\r}{
                %\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\x\paperwidth}{\y\paperheight}, left, base]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB.png}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%% use a small dash ('-') for a bulletpoint list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item}\small\ECFAugie{-}}
%% Frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \vskip17pt
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle \\
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%% Date in the Corner
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \rotatebox{30}{
        \ifx\insertdate\empty\else        
            \hspace*{0.25cm}\ECFAugie\insertshortdate\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \fi
    }
    \vspace*{-1cm}
}

\begin{document}
%\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
   \item<2-> Some text A.
   \item<3-> Some text B.
   \item<4-> Some text on Xela\TeX.  
   \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \visible<5->{
        %\resetcounteronoverlays{smartdiagram}
        \begin{flushleft}
        Engines más utilizados de Latex:
        \end{flushleft}
        \vspace*{-0.25cm}
        \scalebox{0.65}{
        %\setcounter{frame}{0}
        \smartdiagramanimated[bubble diagram]{Motores \\Compiladores\\de Texto,
        \TeX\ (dvi), e\TeX\ ,pdf\TeX, Xe\TeX, \LuaTeX}}
        }
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
        

\end{document}
```

Note that when the slide item is 5, the smartdiagramanimated not begins from 1, in fact from 5; so the item counter needs to be changed to 1.

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Comment: Please make a **minimal** reproducible example

Comment: The MWE uses http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/usergrps/dante/dtk-1.32/dtklogos.sty, Just download it and add to your project as sty file. Regards

Comment: This would make your example compilable, but what you should do is posting minimal example, which only has the code necessary to reproduce your problem, not all your unrelated packages, colour and font changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let beamer uncover your items for you an then use this dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\tikzset{%
   smvisible on/.style={smalt=<+->{}{sminvisible}},
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
   \pause
   \begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \item Some text A.
   \item Some text B.
   \item Some text on Xela
   \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
  \smartdiagramanimated[bubble diagram]{Motores \\Compiladores\\de Texto, TeX\ (dvi), eTeX\ ,pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!! The same can be used with minipage?

Comment: @ABV Why don't you try it with minipages?