# Setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated [descriptive diagram] using Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, smartdiagram

It is needed to implement item counter on smartdiagramanimated [descriptive diagram]  using Beamer, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}%Paquetes para organigramas
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\tikzset{% -- Codigo añadido para contador
   smvisible on/.style={smalt=<+->{}{sminvisible}},
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering


\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
       \pause
       \begin{itemize}[<+->]
       \item Some text A.
       \item Some text B.
       \item Some text C.
       \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
        \smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
            {Latex,{Es un programa especializado en 
                    preparación de documentos.}},
            {Musixtex,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                      especializado en Música.}},
            {Tikz,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                  especializado en gráficos vectoriales.}},
            {Beamer,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                  especializado en diapositivas.}}}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Note that the "descriptive diagram" should start on item 4 not in item 1. I try to use the reference: [Setting item counter on smartdiagramanimated [bubble diagram] using Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675847/setting-item-counter-on-smartdiagramanimated-bubble-diagram-using-beamer) with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}%Paquetes para organigramas
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\tikzset{% -- Codigo añadido para contador
   smvisible on/.style={smalt=<+->{}{sminvisible}},
}%

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramanimated}{r[] m}{%
   \StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% true-no value 1
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}}
   {%false-no value 1
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{}{%
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}
   }{}
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{circular diagram}{% true-circular diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{180+360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\maxsmitem*\xi}
   }
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (-\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
      \node[module,
        drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi)
       at (\angle:\sm@core@circulardistance) {\smitem};
   }
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
     \ifcircularfinalarrowdisabled
       \relax
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
       \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
       \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
         \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
          (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
         }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
          \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
           (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
         }
     \fi
   \else
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\adv}{\xi + 1)}
     \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
     \IfStrEq{\option}{clockwise}{% true-clockwise-circular diagram
       \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
        smvisible on=<\adv->]
         (module\xj) to[bend right] (module\xi);
     }{% false-clockwise-circular diagram
        \draw[diagram arrow type,shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm,
          smvisible on=<\adv->]
         (module\xj) to[bend left] (module\xi);
       }

   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-circular diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{flow diagram}{% true-flow diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0+\xi*\sm@core@modulexsep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(\n2,0) {\smitem};
   }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0-\xi*\sm@core@moduleysep}
        in node[module,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\xi->},
        smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at +(0,\n2) {\smitem};
   }
   }%

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxsmitem) + 1)}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \ifnum\xi<\maxsmitem
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{smart diagram arrow back}
   \draw[diagram arrow type,smvisible on=<\xi->]
     (module\xj) -- (module\xi);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \fi
   % last arrow - not display it in background - check if disabled
   \ifbackarrowdisabled
     \relax
   \else
     \ifnum\xi=\maxsmitem
       \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(0,\sm@core@backarrowdistance) -| (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type, square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
          (module\xj.north) to (module\xi.north);
       }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
         \tikzset{square arrow/.style={
           to path={-- ++(\sm@core@backarrowdistance,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}
           }
         }
         \draw[diagram arrow type,square arrow,smvisible on=<\xi->]
           (module\xj.east) to (module\xi);
       }
     \fi
   \fi
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-flow diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{descriptive diagram}{% true-descriptive diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}

   \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \smitem{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\subitemvisible{\xi}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
   \node[description title,smalt=<.(1)->{drop shadow}{}, smvisible on=<\subitemvisible->]
   (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
   \node[description,smalt=<.(1)->{drop shadow}{},smvisible on=<\subitemvisible->]
   (module\xi)at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
   }{}
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{bubble diagram}{% true-bubble diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->](module\xi)
        at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-bubble diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{constellation diagram}{% true-const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet, smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xi)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   \draw[connection planet satellite, smvisible on=<\xi->]
    (planet) -- (satellite\xi);
 }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{connected constellation diagram}{% true-conn const diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
   \node[planet,smvisible on=<\xi->](planet){\smitem};
   }{%false
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
   \node[satellite,smvisible on=<\xi->] (satellite\xj)
    at (\angle:\sm@core@distanceplanetsatellite) {\smitem };
   }%
   }%
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\xi}{1}{ %true
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
      \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xk}{mod(\xj,\actualnumitem) +1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\smvisible}{\xi+1}
      \path[connection planet satellite,-,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
       (satellite\xj) edge[bend right] (satellite\xk);
   }{}
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}%end-connected constellation diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{priority descriptive diagram}{% true-priority descriptive diagram
   \pgfmathparse{subtract(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth,\sm@core@priorityarrowheadextend)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\sm@core@priorityticksize{\pgfmathresult/2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowtickxshift{(\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth-\sm@core@priorityticksize)/2}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\smvisible{\xi+1}
   \node[description,drop shadow={smvisible on=<\smvisible->},smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
    (module\xi) at (0,0+\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\smitem};
\draw[line width=\sm@core@prioritytick,\col,smvisible on=<\smvisible->]
 ([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)--
 ($([xshift=-\arrowtickxshift pt]module\xi.base west)-(\sm@core@priorityticksize pt,0)$);
   }%
   \coordinate (A) at (module1);
   \coordinate (B) at (module\maxsmitem);
   \CalcHeight(A,B){heightmodules}
   \pgfmathadd{\heightmodules}{\sm@core@priorityarrowheightadvance}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\distancemodules}{\pgfmathresult}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\arrowxshift{\sm@core@priorityarrowwidth/2}
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node[priority arrow] at ([xshift=-\arrowxshift pt]module1.south west){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-priority descriptive diagram
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{sequence diagram}{% true-sequence diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \x[count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \ifnum\xi=1
     \node[sequence item,smvisible on=<\xi->] (sequence-item\xi) {\x};
   \else
     \node[sequence item,anchor=west,smvisible on=<\xi->]
      (sequence-item\xi) at (sequence-item\prevx.east) {\x};
   \fi
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-sequence diagram
   }% end-no value 1
}% end-command


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering


\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
       \pause
       \begin{itemize}[<+->]
       \item Some text A.
       \item Some text B.
       \item Some text C.
       \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\linewidth}
        \smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
            {Latex,{Es un programa especializado en 
                    preparación de documentos.}},
            {Musixtex,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                      especializado en Música.}},
            {Tikz,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                  especializado en gráficos vectoriales.}},
            {Beamer,{Es un paquete de Latex,
                  especializado en diapositivas.}}}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]